# How we can add custom site template in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

In sharepoint Site settings-> under Site Administration ->Sites and workspaces
[image]

Here it is possible to add custom tab for our custom site template ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your web template's Elements.xml file set `DisplayCategory`:

```
<WebTemplate  Name="CustomProjectTemplate"
                Title="Custom Project Site"
                BaseTemplateID="1"
                BaseTemplateName="STS"
                BaseConfigurationID="0"
                ProductVersion="4"
                DisplayCategory="Custom Templates"
                Locale="2057">
  </WebTemplate>
```

Comment: after adding this ,under Custom Templates how we can add our custom templates like template1,template2. Then when i have to create a new site under Custom templates template1,template2. it should display.

Comment: site settings-> Web Designer Galleries -> in solution if i upload a template1.wsp it will come under Custom templates.?

Comment: How are you creating your site templates? Visual Studio?

Comment: I typically create new site templates by customizing an existing site and saving it as a template. You can then further customize the donloaded content of the .wsp (that is in fact a .cab), then re-package it and upload the customized version. See the descritption of a (partly) automated process described here: https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/automating-the-deployment-of-a-customized-project-web-site-template-via-powershell-and-the-managed-client-object-model/